# Can we define view scope in application-context.xml?

Tags: spring, jsf, jsf-2

It is possible in spring application-context.xml file to define a JSF bean with `scope="view"` right now i am using this

```
 <bean id="equipTemplateBean" class="com.alu.ipprd.bsm.soa.portal.bean.sure.EquipmentTemplateBean" parent="mdfBaseBean" scope="session">
     <property name="templatesWorkOrder" ref="templatesWorkOrder" />
</bean>
```

as you can check right now `scope="session"` but i have to use JSF `scope="view"`

Is this technically possible ?

Note:- I don't want to use JSF view scope property in managed bean . I have to use in **application-context.xml** file.

Comment: @BalusC I dont want to use ViewScoped in ManagedBean So i dont think its a duplicate question.

Comment: The duplicate question has more than one answer.

Comment: So can you guide me Which answer is giving proper solution for my problem .

Comment: There are multiple ways to create a custom Spring view scope. Pick your one.

Answer (score 0):

Spring doesn't have a view scope. But since Spring allows to define any custom scope, you can implement it yourself. Have a look at the implementation of [Michail Nikolaev](https://github.com/michail-nikolaev/primefaces-spring-scopes/tree/master/primefaces-scopes-test/src/main/java/org/nkey/primefaces/scopes/test/spring/scope).